# Knot for pulling two branches of a tree together

Tags: knots

I need to bring two branches of a palm tree/bush together. So I need a knot that is secure under tension but can also be progressively tightened.  What knot would you recommend?

Comment: There are various straps and tapes that are used for this that the gardeners will know better than us

Comment: What size branches?  How long do they need to be held together?  Does the connection need to support any other load?  Do you need the branches (or the tree) to survive this treatment?

Comment: Guran - Thanks for this suggestion. I'm going to try to do this with a rope and plastic tubing.  So any knot suggestion(s) would still be appreciated.

Comment: Toby - the branches (really more like 2 trunks of a single plant) are about 4" in diameter.  It was wind and rain that caused the separation.  The angle is now about 40 deg and should be about 20 (more vertical).

Comment: I posted a comment below, but it would be more likely noticed here.  Palm trees are monocots and are not easily damaged by rope (with or without tubing) - the trunks in particular.  From the description, it sounds like a "palm tree/bush", perhaps something like a rapis palm or a small robelenii.  If I didn't have straps already, I certainly wouldn't go out and buy them for this purpose.

Comment: Leaving aside the question of whether you *should* do such a thing to a live tree, I'd use a clove hitch on one branch and a tautline hitch on the other, with the latter being the easiest to reach. You can tighten and loosen it. Loosening it can be useful during or after rain, for instance. The same thing (tautline hitch) is used to secure tent lines, for the same reason (easily adjusted).

Comment: @Ray, I advise you [edit] the question to include the additional information (comments can be removed, without warning).  P.S. Welcome to TGO.se!

Comment: Also, please edit in this info: what is the current orientation and spacing of the two branches?

Answer (score 10):

### I wouldn’t

While I could think of a number of ways to tie a string the way you want, a cam buckle strap would be super simple and (more importantly) damage the bark considerably less.
Even without a cam buckle, I would still advise tape before string.
Professionals use strips of loose fabric to spread the load across the bark as much as possible.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with the prior answer that a rope should not be your permanent solution here, given that it will ultimately damage the tree.  However, I think you can mitigate this for short-term use of rope, until the tree has stabilized itself and no longer needs human help, in one of two ways, possibly both:

1. Chafing gear.  Use scraps of other material as a pad between the
   rope and tree.  A tarp or other strong fabrics might work, but I think the best thing
   here is to run the rope though sections of old garden hose before
   tying your knots.
2. Frequent re-adjusting.  Every couple weeks, remove your rig and
   re-do it in a slightly different place, allowing any friction damage that has occurred to heal.  (It sounds like you already plan to do this.)

Given that, I think the rig you want is some form of trucker's hitch, which is not really a single knot but a combination of multiple knots.  Working together, the different knots form a virtual ratchet strap that holds itself under tension.

For a couple how-to's, here's some links: https://www.animatedknots.com/truckers/index.php and https://www.wikihow.com/Tie-a-Trucker%27s-Hitch.  Normally Animated Knots is quite good, but in this case I think they didn't do well in showing the distinct parts.  Wikihow's drawings can be hard to interpret, but give a decent idea of what is going on.